# Correlation Between Two Skellam-Distributed Random Variables

Tags: poisson-process, bivariate-distributions, copula

I have two Skellam-distributed random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, with rate parameters $\mu_{1,+}, \mu_{1,-}$ and $\mu_{2,+}, \mu_{2,-}$ respectively.  (For my case, it just so happens that their distributions are symmetric, i.e. $\mu_{1,+} = \mu_{1,-}$ and $\mu_{2,+} = \mu_{2,-}$.)  Now I want to figure out how to describe/model/estimate the joint distribution of these processes.  Note, I can simulate time series of $X_1$ and $X_2$ through a highly-complex nonlinear model.

There is literature [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/pub/reports/na/Correlated_Poisson_Processes_1.pdf) that discusses an extension to the Common Shock Model that is often applied to RVs with Poisson marginals.  I wonder if somehow the Common Shock Model can be applied to Skellam RVs?  Of if there is another way to approach this problem?

(Can a moderator please add the tags "skellam-distribution" and possibly "copula" or "common-shock-model"?)

Comment: The idea of using Poisson processes here is heavily dependent on the sum of two poissons also being a poisson, however it does seem that the sum of two Skellams is also Skellam, so you might be onto something ;)

Comment: Probably you should go through the article step by step and try to reproduce the work but using Skellams